# Lazy Loading, no chunks - Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading

I'm trying to do Lazy Loading,
and followed the steps in the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#routes-at-the-app-level) of angular.
The problem is that there is no chunks that is showing.

Is there any steps that I forgot that causing this?

**App Routing**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'prospect',
    loadChildren: './prospect/prospect.module#ProspectModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'customer',
    loadChildren: './customer/customer.module#CustomerModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
  // { path: '**', redirectTo: '/error-404' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**prospect Routing**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ProspectComponent } from './prospect.component';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProspectComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProspectRoutingModule { }
```

**prospect Module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CustomerRoutingModule } from './customer-routing.module';

import { CustomerComponent } from './customer.component';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CustomerRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [CustomerComponent],
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

**customer Routing**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { CustomerComponent } from './customer.component';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CustomerComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CustomerRoutingModule { }
```

**customer Module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ProspectRoutingModule } from './prospect-routing.module';

import { ProspectComponent } from './prospect.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProspectRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ProspectComponent]
})
export class ProspectModule { }
```

[image]
I notice that it produces chunk when I do ng serve.

[image]

Did I implement Lazy loding correctly?

Comment: Can you put the code of your prospect.module too

Comment: @DulanjayaTennekoon alright i will put it.

Comment: What you have included in your update is, the other routing module. Can you add the ProspectModule

Comment: @DulanjayaTennekoon done adding the other module

Comment: It seems like everything fine. But there was a concern in the import RouterModule.forRoot(routes) in Angular 4 where chunks do not appear. I am still not sure whether that is the problem

Comment: @DulanjayaTennekoon yes I read about that, I'm just worried that in official docs that it said it should show the chunks but it shows ngfactory instead.

Comment: what version of angular are you using? and the cli?

Comment: @brijmcq I'm using version 7.2.0 for angulat and the cli.

Answer (score 2):

do you use services from lazy loading module in your app? If you don't use a shared module you can break lazy loading.

Comment: I did not use services. 
What I did is just I follow the step by step instruction in angular docs lazy loading. (https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#routes-at-the-app-level)[https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#routes-at-the-app-level]

Answer (score 0):

i change in your App routing's route const, please this...

```
const routes: Routes = [    
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: 'prospect',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
   path: 'prospect',
   loadChildren: './prospect/prospect.module#ProspectModule'
},
{
   path: 'customer',
   loadChildren: './customer/customer.module#CustomerModule'
},
// { path: '**', redirectTo: '/error-404' }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use "module": "commonjs" in tsconfig.json **compilerOptions** section. Try "module": "esnext"